# Анти-скриншот на python

Tags: python, безопасность, скриншот

Работодатель захотел контролировать процессы работы с помощью какой то шпионской программы, которая делает скриншоты рабочего стола.
Подскажите можно ли написать скрипт на python который будет блокировать программы для скриншотов?

Comment: Скрипт называется "уволиться с работы"

Comment: надо ломать системный вызов который скриншотит. простым скриптом не сделаешь.

Comment: если подписал соглашение о слежке - то ничего с этим не сделаешь. если в трудовом договоре этого нет, то 138-я статья Уголовного кодекса РФ

Comment: Ну ок, сделаете вы скрипт, который заблокирует сбор скриншотов. Контролирующий человек обратит внимание на то, что с вашего компьютера скришоты не приходят, или приходят одинаковые. Вы получите втык, к вам сразу будет пристальное внимание (раз прячитесь, значит вам есть что скрывать). А в зависимости от воли руководства и подписанных документов можете получить штраф или более серьёзные проблемы. Нет, в такой ситуации нужно либо увольняться, либо принимать правила и следовать им.

Comment: https://windowsreport.com/anti-screen-capture-software/

Answer (score 0):

Можно поискать папку, куда эти скрины валяться. Скорее всего в именах файлов присутствует дата. Так что может помочь регулярка. Потом удаляем оттуда всё и делаем несколько скринов как вы работаете над кодом добавляем и делаем это регуглярно (можно скрипт сделать), а что не надо, не скрините. Удачи ;)

Comment: Это очень натянутое предположение, что программа куда-то будет скрины в открытом виде складывать и не отправлять долгое время.

Comment: @Kromster Ну может быть ;)